# Why the code doesn't change .properties file

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I have the following code which must add new values to the existing properties in the .properties file of, if the property doesn't exist - create it.

```java
public String saveProperties(ArrayList<Property> properties, String customerId){
            final String userPropFieldName = "users." + customerId + ".rules";
            try{
                PropertiesConfiguration props = new PropertiesConfiguration("/home/mikhail/bzrrep/DLP/DLPServer/src/main/resources/rules.properties");

                for (Property property: properties){
                    String fieldName = "rules." + property.getName() + "." + property.getType();
                    String[] values = (property.getValue()).split("\\,");
                    for (String word: values){
                        System.out.print(word + " ");
                    }

                    if (util.exist(fieldName, props)){
                        props.setProperty(fieldName, values);
                    } else {
                        props.addProperty(fieldName, values);
                    }

                    String[] userProperties = props.getStringArray(userPropFieldName);
                    if (property.getAccepted()){
                        userProperties = util.addNewValue(userProperties, fieldName);
                    } else {
                        userProperties = util.removeValue(userProperties, fieldName);
                    }
                    props.setProperty(userPropFieldName, userProperties);
                }
            }catch (ConfigurationException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return "Saved";
    }
```

I run it with the debugger and all values right, I mean, there are the proper name of the property and the proper values in the array, so, seen that it came up to the adding or setting new value, but finally I didn't see any changes in the property file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your modified properties to file

```
props.save();
```

Read more: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Saving

BTW, Saving properties directly to source code (*src/main/resources/rules.properties*) is usually bad idea.

Comment: Oh, yes. I've been gazing into the code and couldn't find the problem. and about saving to the source code I know. It's just temporarily